# Upstash for Redis Connection Issue: Why does Redis connection keep dropping?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, redis, celery

I'm working on a Python app using Flask. I'm also using rabbitmq, redis, celery, and have deployed my app to heroku to host it. My app takes quite a while to render output because there's so much analysis that needs to take place. This is why I've tried to enlist the help of redis and celery. Before I run my app, here's my order of operations:

```
brew services start rabbitmq
brew services start redis
celery -A app2.celery_app worker --loglevel=info
```

Once these are running successfully, I try to run my app script:

```
python3 app2.py
```

I'm just testing now on a local host, so upon loading that URL, I submit my URL, sitemap, and input_file.xlsx (as required by my app). It runs for a few seconds, then crashes. I've tried increasing dynos in heroku, but think the issue is largely owed to redis since this is the error I'm getting:

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection closed by server.
```

**For reference, here's my existing app script:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from rake_nltk import Rake
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from multiprocessing import Queue
import threading
import os
import json
from openpyxl import Workbook
from celery import Celery
from kombu import Queue
from kombu.common import Broadcast
import redis


upstash_url = "https://us1-proud-sculpin-38252.upstash.io"
upstash_token = "xxxxx"

# Set a value
set_url = f"{upstash_url}/set"
set_payload = {
    "key": "foo",
    "value": "bar",
    "auth": upstash_token
}
response = requests.post(set_url, json=set_payload)
print(response.json())

# Get a value
get_url = f"{upstash_url}/get"
get_payload = {
    "key": "foo",
    "auth": upstash_token
}
response = requests.post(get_url, json=get_payload)
print(response.json())

app = Flask(__name__)
ON_HEROKU = os.environ.get('ON_HEROKU')

# Initialize the Celery app instance
celery_app = Celery('GPT_app2', broker='amqp://localhost:5672', backend='redis://default:xxxxx@us1-proud-sculpin-38252.upstash.io:38252')

# Function to find synonyms for a given word using NLTK
def find_synonyms(word):
    synonyms = []
    if isinstance(word, str):
        for syn in wordnet.synsets(word):
            for lemma in syn.lemmas():
                synonyms.append(lemma.name())
    return synonyms

# Function to check if a URL returns a 404 status code
def is_404(url):
    try:
        response = requests.head(url)
        return response.status_code == 404
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        return False

@celery_app.task
def internal_linking_script(url, absolute_rute, list_keyword_url):
    internal_linking_opportunities = []

    try:
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
        source_paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
        source_paragraphs = [x.text for x in source_paragraphs]

        # Extract paragraphs that contain links
        link_paragraphs = []
        for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'):
            # Find all links within the paragraph
            links = paragraph.find_all('a')
            if len(links) > 0:
                # If there are links, append the paragraph to the list
                link_paragraphs.append(paragraph)

        # More script...

    return serializable_opportunities

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/analyze', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def analyze():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the website URL, sitemap URL, and input file from the form
        website_url = request.form['website_url']
        sitemap_url = request.form['sitemap_url']
        input_file = request.files['input_file']

        # Save the input file
        input_file.save(secure_filename(input_file.filename))

        # Read the input file
        list_keywords = pd.read_excel(input_file.filename, usecols=[0, 1, 2])
        list_keyword_url = list_keywords.values.tolist()

        # Crawl the sitemap or homepage based on the provided URL
        if sitemap_url:
            response = requests.get(sitemap_url)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                root = ET.fromstring(response.content)

                urls = []
                for elem in root.iter('{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}loc'):
                    urls.append(elem.text)
            else:
                urls = [website_url]
        else:
            urls = [website_url]

        # Start the internal linking script as a Celery task for each URL
        tasks = []
        for url in urls:
            task = internal_linking_script.delay(url, website_url, list_keyword_url)
            tasks.append(task)

        # Wait for all tasks to complete and gather the results
        internal_linking_opportunities = []
        for task in tasks:
            result = task.get()
            internal_linking_opportunities.extend(result)

        # Save the DataFrame to an XLSX file
        output_file = "internal_linking_opportunities.xlsx"
        df = pd.DataFrame(internal_linking_opportunities, columns=["Keyword", "Text", "Source URL", "Target URL", "Link Presence", "Position"])
        df.to_excel(output_file, index=False)

        # Provide the file as a download to the user
        return send_file(output_file, as_attachment=True)

    return render_template('result.html', result=internal_linking_opportunities)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 17995 if ON_HEROKU else 5500))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

**Also for reference, here is my celery_tasks.py file:**

```
from celery import Celery
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from rake_nltk import Rake
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import redis

app = Celery('celery_tasks', broker='amqp://localhost:5672')

def find_synonyms(word):
    synonyms = []
    if isinstance(word, str):
        for syn in wordnet.synsets(word):
            for lemma in syn.lemmas():
                synonyms.append(lemma.name())
    return synonyms

def is_404(url):
    try:
        response = requests.head(url)
        return response.status_code == 404
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        return False

# Establish a Redis connection
redis_host = 'us1-proud-sculpin-38252.upstash.io'
redis_port = 38252
redis_password = 'xxxxx'
redis_db = 0
redis_client = redis.Redis(host=redis_host, port=redis_port, password=redis_password, db=redis_db)


@app.task
def internal_linking_script(urls, absolute_rute, list_keyword_url):
    internal_linking_opportunities = []

    for iteration in urls:
        try:
            page = requests.get(iteration)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
            source_paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
            source_paragraphs = [x.text for x in source_paragraphs]

            link_paragraphs = []
            for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'):
                links = paragraph.find_all('a')
                if len(links) > 0:
                    link_paragraphs.append(paragraph)

            links = []
            for paragraph in link_paragraphs:
                for link in paragraph.find_all('a'):
                    links.append(link.get('href'))

            for x in list_keyword_url:
                keyword = x[0]
                synonyms = find_synonyms(keyword)
                related_keywords = []
                for kw in [keyword] + synonyms:
                    r = Rake()
                    r.extract_keywords_from_text('\n'.join(source_paragraphs))
                    keyword_scores = r.get_word_degrees()
                    for word in [kw]:
                        if word in keyword_scores:
                            related_keywords += r.get_ranked_phrases_with_scores()

                for paragraph in source_paragraphs:
                    if (" " + str(keyword).lower() + " " in " " + str(paragraph).lower().replace(",", "").replace(".", "").replace(";", "").replace("?", "").replace("!", "") + " "
                        or any(synonym in str(paragraph).lower() for synonym in synonyms)):
                        links_presence = False
                        for link in links:
                            try:
                                if link.startswith(absolute_rute):
                                    if requests.head(link).status_code == 200:
                                        soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).text, 'html.parser')
                                        for link_2 in soup_2.find_all('a'):
                                            if x[2].startswith(absolute_rute):
                                                if x[2] == urljoin(absolute_rute, link_2.get('href')):
                                                    links_presence = True
                                            elif x[2] == link_2.get('href'):
                                                links_presence = True
                                    elif is_404(link):
                                        links_presence = '404'
                            except (AttributeError, requests.exceptions.RequestException):
                                pass

                        if links_presence == False:
                            internal_linking_opportunities.append(
                                [keyword, paragraph, iteration, x[2], False, x[1]])
                        elif links_presence == '404':
                            internal_linking_opportunities.append(
                                [keyword, paragraph, iteration, x[2], '404', x[1]])
                        else:
                            internal_linking_opportunities.append(
                                [keyword, paragraph, iteration, x[2], True, x[1]])
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error fetching URL '{iteration}': {e}")

    # Store the result in Redis
    redis_key = f"internal_linking_opportunities:{urls[0]}"
    redis_client.set(redis_key, internal_linking_opportunities)

    return 'Processing completed!'
```

Is there anything you see that might be causing this redis issue? This is my first time using rabbitmq, redis, and celery. Please assume I know nothing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: redis urls don't typically have a username in them.  try removing `default` from your backend url.